# Moringa Oleifera tree growing a foreign green leafed plant

Tags: diagnosis

I have a 7 year old Moringa tree growing a foreign plant from its branches which become a green bundle on the tree. What could this be

Comment: Please add a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Moringa is a fairly plain tree with uncomplicated pinnate leaves so this is unlikely to be a reversion to type of complex leaves to simple leaves. More likely in a warm humid environment such as the tropics this could be an orchid which has become naturally implanted on the tree. See [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyuq_IASSRU) for an example of how a Dendrobium orchid can be attached to a tree. Compare your odd growth (particularly leaves and roots and way it is attached to the tree) and see if it resembles an orchid.